# Get Data from function in insert

Tags: t-sql

While doing

```
create table #tmpsr(
srid int,
W_DiffOriginal decimal(12,2)
)
insert into #tmpsr
        (srid,W_DiffOriginal)
        select sr_id,  --- From Table
        W_DiffOriginal=DiffOriginal --- From Function
        From TBL_SR,dbo.fnc_VoucherDetails_Get(sr_id) ---Table-Valued Function
        Where   SRdoid = 12811 --- Column in the table TBL_SR
        and fsrid=sr_id ---fsrid: Columns in the Table-Valued Function,
```

I Got the message :

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>   Invalid column name 'sr_id'.

Any Idea?

Comment: Can you please re format the question properly ?

Answer (score 1):

i think error is coming because you are calling function in form clause

`select .... From TBL_SR,dbo.fnc_VoucherDetails_Get(sr_id)` in this case its not able to get what is sr_id

so to resolve this call function in your select statement like this

```
create table #tmpsr( 
srid int, 
W_DiffOriginal decimal(12,2) 
) 
insert into #tmpsr 
        (srid,W_DiffOriginal) 
        select sr_id,  --- From Table 
        (select W_DiffOriginal from dbo.fnc_VoucherDetails_Get(sr_id))=DiffOriginal ---From Function 
        From TBL_SR, ---Table-Valued Function 
        Where   SRdoid = 12811 --- Column in the table TBL_SR
```

this may resolve your issue

Comment: fsrid is a column from function, how can your query work in that case?

Comment: in where clause there's fsrid column, which isn't TBL_SR table's column. (---fsrid: Columns in the Table-Valued Function), that's why your query won't work. I suppose @Miron is trying to get table dynamically from his function.

Comment: removed it because no need for that now becuase its already in the select form clause

Comment: I am trying to find a better way than select ... The function returns about 20 fields ... I don't want to select the same record 20 times...

Thnx